# Integrated Webcam of Dell XPS 13 2in1 is not detected on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, dell, webcam, xps

I am a very basic user of Ubuntu, so i would be very thankful for a bit of help here.
I just recently switched from Win 10 to Ubuntu 20.04 and chose the "stupid people" version where a lot of drivers are already pre-installed. My microphone and my keyboard and so on all work fine, but my webcam does not.
When opening "Cheese" i just get a message "no device found"
I found some advice online that told me to try this:

```
padit1337@xps:~$ ls /dev/video*
```

to see if it detects a cam, but i got this feedback

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

And i also checked that the webcam is activated in the UEFI, so thats not the problem.

I have very limited insight in how Ubuntu works, hence after googling for an hour I don't think i will find anything useful without a humans help.

EDIT:
I insert some infos requested in the comments.

```
padit1337@xps:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 27c6:532d Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

padit1337@xps:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 8a12 (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G7 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a19 (rev 03)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 03)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 03)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 USB Controller (rev 03)
00:0d.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 NHI #0 (rev 03)
00:0d.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Ice Lake Thunderbolt 3 NHI #1 (rev 03)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 34fc (rev 30)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 34ef (rev 30)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Killer Wi-Fi 6 AX1650i 160MHz Wireless Network Adapter (201NGW) (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:15.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #3 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Management Engine Interface (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34b7 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
57:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation Device 0001
58:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)

padit1337@xps:~$ lsmod | grep video
video                  49152  3 dell_wmi,dell_laptop,i915

padit1337@xps:~$ ls /dev | grep video
```

nothing happend after inserting this last comand.

```
padit1337@xps:~$ uname -a
Linux xps 5.8.0-53-generic #60~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 09:52:46 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

padit1337@xps:~$ dmesg | grep "video"
```

nothing happend after this last comand.

Comment: Your computer's web cam may be too new. Try Ubuntu 21.04 live installation USB in the "Try Ubuntu" mode without installing and see if the web cam is recognized in the newer version. If so, upgrade to 21.04 from within the installed 20.04 version.

Comment: Could yo ube more specific about what is the *"stupid people" version*?

Comment: check also please in uefi/Bios if your camera is not disabled.

Answer (score -1):

If you search the web there are posts that indicate an ongoing bug.  Apparently many Ubuntu 20.04 kernals do not recognize the built in webcam. The bug was fixed but came back in later kernels.  I too am not an advanced user and I have the same machine you do but I haven't figured out how to get it to work.